# How to make sure that pg_restore is running?

Tags: postgresql

I ran `pg_restore` command for restoring a postgres database. The binary data dump is about 1.3GB and it has been restoring for 3 hours. Is there a way to make sure it is actually still running ? and maybe check the progress ?

I can see there is a stable CPU activity for WindowServer.

Comment: Is it the CPU activity stable at a high level or a low one?

Comment: @jjanes CPU is stable at a low level. WindowServer takes about 40% of the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

If the command hasn't finished, it is by definition still running. To see if it is processing, check if it keeps a CPU core busy and have a look at `pg_stat_activity`: if the corresponding server process has no `wait_event`, it is running.

Comment: thank you. I checked pg_stat_activity but not sure how to interpret it. There are two rows with the db name on the datname column. One row has wait_event null and state active. The other row has wait_event "Client" and state idle.

Comment: One of these sessions will be the one that is running the `pg_stat_activity` query, that is the one without `wait_event`. Look at `application_name`, `query` and `backend_type` of the other session to find out if it is your `pg_restore`. Examine `wait_event_type` and `wait_event` to get a clue what it is waiting for.

Comment: Ah I saw the idle one has backend_start at the time I started the restore run, so I assume the restoration is still running.

Comment: Thank you. I felt the one with `wait_event` ClientRead is the db restoration job. It has `application_name` pgAdmin4: DB:<new DB name>, `query` selects "session_stats" and "tps_stats" with oid filters. It also has `backend_start` time at the time I started the restoration. The other row with null in `wait_event` has `query` select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = <new DB name>

Comment: Then the `pg_restore` is done, and it is probably pgAdmin that is confused. Why are you using that tool instead of launching `pg_restore` yourself?